# How to store a uint[] memory inside a struct in solidity

Tags: solidity, struct, memory

I have the below code

```
struct Ticket {
        uint256 id;
        uint256[] numbers;
        address payable owner;
}


function enter(uint256[] memory userNumbers) public {
        Ticket memory newTicket = Ticket(
            id,
            userNumbers,
            payable(msg.sender)
        );

        entries[id][msg.sender] = newTicket;
    }
```

However, when I inspect the Ticket object saved, I only get the `id`, and `address`.

How should I properly save the `userNumbers` inside the struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me. But it does not show the dynamic array in Remix if that is what you mean? However, this does not mean that the array is not there. It just seems like a UI bug/limitation.

I wrote this code to test it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract StackOverflowAnswer {

  struct Ticket {
        uint id;
        uint[] numbers;
        address payable owner;
  }
  mapping(uint => mapping(address => Ticket)) public entries;

  function enter(uint256[] memory userNumbers, uint id) public {

    Ticket memory newTicket = Ticket(
        id,
        userNumbers,
        payable(msg.sender)
    );
    
    entries[id][msg.sender] = newTicket;
  }

  function seeTicket(uint id, address _address) public view returns (uint[] memory) {
    return entries[id][_address].numbers;
  }
}
```

I wrote an additional method just to retrieve the dynamic array part of the struct, and it renders it when specifically selected, I guess:

[image]

Comment: yes, that's what I meant. Remix does not show/display the array. and ....hoolllyyyy........ you are right! Would you know why this is? I suddenly don't feel comfortable with how I wrote it now since it gets buggy on remix...

Comment: I am not sure why they won't show it. Still, I know that in the past, they had even more significant limitations (you couldn't create a list of lists at all, not because of solidity or javascript by themselves, but due to the translation between them, at least now you can, but it just won't display correctly I suppose).

You could also try developing outside of Remix like in Hardhat that should work, and then use test-driven development to ensure that everything is built the way you want it :-)